# Holding a URL parameter between pages?

Tags: php, javascript, url, variables, web

I want to store a variable in the URL while they are browsing.

For example:
A menu, when the user selects ?category=shopping it goes to a map with shopping and they can click on a  place and it should go to ?category=shop&id=22.

If they return to the menu then the ?category should be removed and if they click on something else e.g ?category=cafe.

I've been really puzzled with this and would appreciate any help - thanks!

Comment: Hi John, could you expand your question a bit? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. E.g., what decides what the category should be? Is this something they've selected from the menu? If so, when does it need to get unset?

Comment: You might want to look into $_GET['category'] as this will return "shop" in your example. respectively $_GET['id'] will return 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to store state between pages, as your title suggests, then you can store this information inside the `$_SESSION` superglobal array. You start a new session by running `session_start()` as the very first line of any new page, before any output is sent to the browser. Anything you then store inside of `$_SESSION` will be available when you start the session in the same way on the next page.

If you're only interested in building a query string (i.e. the `?field=value&field2=value2` portion of the URL), as the content of your question indicates, then you might want to take a look at the [`http_build_query()`](http://ca.php.net/http_build_query) function.

Your question seems a little ambiguous to me as to what your actual goal is for this, so I gave you both approaches. Just remember that you should use `$_SESSION` for state, and `http_build_query()` for creating dynamic URLs to point to specific content. Also remember that if the data needs to be secure, then you shouldn't put it in the URL or anywhere else the user could modify it, or where others could read it (e.g. in the browsers address bar). That sort of information needs to be in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what's wrong with my answer? If I've misunderstood the question, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: +1 I was just going to suggest using `parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` in combination with `http_build_query()`. Might solve the OP's problem, but the question is not that clear.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a good use for session variables.

```
$_SESSION["category"]="stuff";
```

you can then keep it until you dont want it any more, or they terminate their session

Comment: But it would need to change if the user returns to the menu again?

Comment: Thats OK, change it as/when you want. But it will stay the same till you change it, or they end the session.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to store a variable in the URL while they are browsing.

You can't actually "store" anything in the URL.
If you want to pass some *data* from one page to another using query string, you have to add this data to the query string.

"A map with shopping" should add category to the every it's link.
That's the way every web application works.

Session is not the way to go, because **every page on the site should have it's address**, and your category being important part of this address. If you store it in the session, no bookmark can be added, no link to be sent to a friend and no search engine will index your goods.